# How many matrices does SO(2) contain?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, orthogonal-matrices

Would I be correct in saying that the special orthogonal group SO(2) contains one matrix , namely;

$A=\begin{pmatrix}{}
\cos\theta& -\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta&\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}$

or would it have infinitely many matrices as $\theta $ can be any angle between 0 and 360, and different angles would produce different entries ?

Comment: The matrices are all of that form, but (assuming that the underlying field is $\mathbb R$ or something similar) there is an infinite number of them.

Comment: Please: **infinitely many** matrices, not **infinite** matrices.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Good point, I'll edit it now :)

Comment: As many matrices as there are options for $\theta$

Comment: there are exactly as many matrices as there are numbers in $[0,2\pi)$, which is to say uncountably many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infinitely many matrices: $$ {\rm SO}(2,\Bbb R) = \left\{A=\begin{pmatrix}{}
\cos\theta& -\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta&\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}\mid \theta \in \Bbb R \right\}. $$For example, for $\theta  = 0$ and $\theta = \pi/2$ we get $$\begin{pmatrix}{}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}{}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \in {\rm SO}(2,\Bbb R).$$